# Appropriate visualization for the Wilcoxon signed rank test

Tags: statistical-significance, data-visualization, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have question regarding the Wilcoxon test and if the results can be represented visually.

I had 10 participants in my experiment where by I asked participants to read sentences and then they repeated the sentences (there were three different types of repetitions- analogous to three different treatments) and then a post testing period.

Thus I had Pre_treatment 1 vs. Post treatment_1, Pre_treatment 2 vs. Post treatment_2, Pre_treatment 3 vs. Post treatment_3.

My results were significant but I wasn't sure how to represent the results since using mean won't make sense.

Also, is there any other test I could employ? (I did use a parametric repeated measures ANOVA in first pass but since the sample size was small I didn't think it was appropriate.)

Comment: Under the assumption of symmetry used by the Wilcoxon test, all location parameters are equivalent, provided of course that they exist.

Answer (score 1):

Boxplots are very useful for visualization of such data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The test sounds fine. Check that you meet the [assumptions of the test](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-using-spss-statistics.php). The most important assumption to check is that the distribution of the differences is symmetric in shape. If that doesn't hold, take a look at the [sign test](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/sign-test-using-spss-statistics.php) which doesn't have that assumption but isn't as powerful.

For the Wilcoxon signed rank test, I saw this visualization once in a text book. Unfortunately, I've forgotten which one.

[image]